# Execute a command on remote machine with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, invoke-command

I try to execute a simple command on a remote machine with PowerShell (run as administrator).

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName xxxxx -Credential xxx -ScriptBlock{notepad}
```

But I have the following issue:

```
[computer name] Connecting to remote server  failed with
the following error message : Access is denied. For more information,
see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionStateBroken
```

Before that:

1. I changed the policy on both machines with:

   ```
   Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope LocalMachine -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
   ```
2. And I enabled running PowerShell commands on remote computer:

   ```
   Enable-PSRemoting -Force
   ```

But when I do `Enable-PSRemoting -Force` on the remote machine I have the following error:

```
Set-WSManQuickConfig : <f:WSManFault xmlns:f="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wsmanfault" Code="2150859113" Machine="localhost">
<f:Message>
<f:ProviderFault provider="Config provider" path="%systemroot%\system32\WsmSvc.dll">
<f:WSManFault xmlns:f="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wsmanfault" Code="2150859113" Machine="xxxxxx">
<f:Message>
WinRM firewall exception will not work since one of the network connection
types on this machine is set to Public. Change the network connection type
to either Domain or Private and try again.
</f:Message>
</f:WSManFault>
</f:ProviderFault>
</f:Message>
</f:WSManFault>
At line:116 char:17
+                 Set-WSManQuickConfig -force
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Set-WSManQuickConfig], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WsManError,Microsoft.WSMan.Management.SetWSManQuickConfigCommand
```

Comment: Use `-SkipNetworkProfileCheck` although I'm not sure why your NIC is set to Public.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I seem to recall having a similar issue with a VM that had an 2nd interface in a host-only network.